# NotesServiceRuntimeException occurs when running jar

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, executable-jar

I am creating a program in Java to send emails out through IBM Lotus Notes using Notes.jar

When I run my code from Eclipse it runs perfectly and does everything I want it to do.

When I generate a jar for my program and include all references, I get

> NotesServiceRuntimeException saying Local Notes Installation is not
>   found

Need help!!

Comment: Perhaps there is a path variable that Eclipse is setting, but is not being set when running the .jar

Comment: yea I believe so, any idea what this path and where I should set it?

Comment: Window->Preferences, then browse to Java->Build Path->Classpath Variables and Java-Build Path->User Libraries. The jars specified there will give you an idea on what you will need in your classpath to remove the errors you are seeing.

Comment: check that the notes dlls are also in the classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

I needed to include the location of where Lotus Notes is installed in the System Path